# Разрешения экранов при верстке

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Подскажите почему пишет айфон 5 разрешение 320? хотя у него 640 и в айфон 6+ 414 хотя больше чем в раза больше?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Потому что 1px в css и на экране компьютера не равен 1px на экране телефонов с высоким DPI. Отладчик Chrome это знает и пропорционально увеличивает все элементы и текст на странице. Кроме изображений. Чтобы подстроиться под это дело и Ваши картинки отображались на DPI устройствах согласно вашему макету, стоит использовать атрибут [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset).